# How can I remove a folder with a lock icon on it?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, 20.04, windows, directory

My laptop is configured to dual-boot with Windows. I use OneDrive and I have a folder that I want to copy from that folder to Ubuntu but I later realized that it doesn't work that way, now I can't delete the folder I copied from the OneDrive folder from Windows partition to Ubuntu. The error says "permission denied." How can I remove the folder?

Comment: Can you `cd` to that folder via a terminal? What is it's location?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach can be to go to the parent folder of the folder you have copied and check the ownership of the folder through the terminal or basic GUI.

run the command on terminal to check the ownership

```
ls -la [folder]
```

if the owner of the folder is an accessible account then login as that account or sudo as the account, [change the permissions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) of the folder and delete it.

If the above is not possible then [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) as root and delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Folders or files show lock icon in linux/ubuntu when windows os doesn't shutdown properly. For this you have to remount the drive with read & write permission. Then shutdown and start your laptop.
Steps:-
1> df -h
This command tells you the device name.
2> sudo mount -o remount,rw '/dev/sda3'

```
    This is the command to remount where '/dev/sda3' should be your device name got from the first command.
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

I hope following 2 easy steps will do that.

1.) Fireup Terminal and run `sudo nautilus`

2.) Simply browse and delete.

***N.B- How it will affect you by deleting that folder, it's upto it. I just wrote how to delete one.***